# RUST macro_rules pattern matching to match arbitary sings

Tags: rust

I am trying to define a RUST macro that can be invoked like as follows.
The key being the macro_rules being able to match the variadic "...", which is rust 1.45.0 is a type equivalent to C variadic

```
hookv! {
unsafe fn open(path: *const c_char, flags: c_int, args: ...) -> c_int => my_open {
    if let Ok(path) = std::str::from_utf8(std::ffi::CStr::from_ptr(path).to_bytes()) {
        if path == "test-panic" {
            panic!("Testing panics");
        }
        println!("open(\"{}\")", path);
    } else {
        println!("open(...)");
    }

    realv!(open)(path, flags, args)
   }
}
```

The following macro_rules cant handle it.

```
macro_rules! hookv {
(unsafe fn $real_fn:ident ( $($v:ident : $t:ty),* ) -> $r:ty => $hook_fn:ident $body:block) => {
......
```

I am looking to understand how can define the macro_rules! to handle pattern matching something like args: ... which is a legal way to define a rust function in 1.45.0

Comment: Did you try `tt` (token tree)?